# Get UserName when login with Facebook using SDK 3.15 in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Today I was trying to implement the new Facebook sdk v3.15.0 and I had a problem with retrieving username after getting `GraphUser` object.

Before implementing the new Facebook SDK I was using `facebook-android-sdk-3.7` and I managed to receive username, here i will post my GraphUser object:

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"10000*******","first_name":"****","username":"him.her","timezone":2,"email":"ultimo****@yahoo.com","verified":true,"name":"*** D**a","locale":"en_US","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/k***o.d****","last_name":"D****a","gender":"male","updated_time":"2014-03-03T10:10:54+0000"}}
```

When I implemented the new Facebook SDK, the GraphUser object that I received was this:

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"153****","first_name":"***i","timezone":2,"email":"ol***@yahoo.it","verified":true,"name":"O*** S***","locale":"en_US","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/1*****","last_name":"****e","gender":"male","updated_time":"2014-04-22T19:59:34+0000"}
```

I use this to get the GraphUser:

```
......
@Override
public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) { ....
```

**Problem**

How can I get the username when I log in with Facebook with the new SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `username` field is no longer available with the Graph API v2.0. Have a look at my answer here: [Omniauth-facebook hash not showing Facebook 'username' field, using rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884511/omniauth-facebook-hash-not-showing-facebook-username-field-using-rails-3/23884721#23884721)

Comment: So what is the solution ?